# How to use a If statement within a for loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

In column D, I am trying to delete every row that has a value in it. If the cell is blank, it is not deleted

The For loop only looks at D2 and deletes the entire row because it has a value in it. The loop then stops, and does not continue. The NumRows value is 9324 because there are that many rows in column A.

I'm stuck and cannot figure out how to get the loop to continue. Thanks!

```
Dim VarDeleteLoop as long
Dim NumRows As Long


NumRows = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(Application.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For VarDeleteLoop = 2 To NumRows

        Cells(VarDeleteLoop, 4).Select

        If Cells(VarDeleteLoop, 4).Value = "" Then
                Cells(VarDeleteLoop, 4).Select
        Else
                Cells(VarDeleteLoop, 4).Select
                Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If

Next VarDeleteLoop
```

Comment: When the loop stops, do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Also, you should change `Application.Rows.Count` to `Worksheets("Sheet").Rows.Count`

Comment: I actually don't get any error. It just deletes the rows and ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When removing things, it is often a better idea to do it backwards. That way you don't need to keep track of the number of the next line, if the previous one was deleted.

Do your for loop like this instead:

```
For VarDeleteLoop = NumRows To 2 Step -1
```

Comment: That worked! I'm new to VBA, only just started working in it about 2 weeks ago, so still have a lot of learning to do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

.AutoFilter can quickly isolate non-blank cells and identify them for deletion.

```
With Worksheets("sheet").Columns("D").Cells
    If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
        If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```